# Setting up WordPress and Moodle on separate servers with distinct subpaths while mapping a single domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, ssl, moodle

I've spent some time on this and am pretty sure I've seen it done before, but it's not working for me. Here's what's going on:

My client current hosts both a WordPress and Moodle instance on one server (let's call this Server A). The wordpress site can be accessed via [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) and the Moodle instance by [www.website.com/learn](http://www.website.com/learn). The client wants to move their Moodle instance to a different server, but still keep the DNS and subpath the same. I.e. [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) (wordpress) will be hosted on Server A and [www.website.com/learn](http://www.website.com/learn) (moodle) will be hosted on Server B.

Server A contains a lets encrypt SSL. I do not have access to the actual certs on the server, but I do have access to the cert files content via the service provider. Note: Server A is with one provider and Server B with another.

I have moved the Moodle instance over to Server B and made sure that it's accessible via server-b-ip-address/learn, but I can't seem to figure out how to get Server B to be secure and for the site on Server B to be accessible via [www.website.com/learn](http://www.website.com/learn)

I've tried a bunch of different things, but feel that I should not state them here and try and keep an open mind on all possible answers I might get and should try then again as recommended.

Please feel free to ask questions about what I've tried etc. The list is long. I did most of this work late at night and early into the morning, so I most likely missed some stuff.

Info:

- Server A only has an online portal that I can access it by
- Server B is an ubuntu 20.04 server with apache2, php, etc.
- The client does NOT want to use a sub domain. Has to be via subpaths

**Edit 1**: Last thing I tried was adding a sub domain and pointing it to Server B. This did work, but server B still shows as unsecure with openssl certificates. As mentioned, the client doesn't like this approach.

Comment: You may be able to configure the web server on your `www.example.com` domain as a reverse proxy server, to  forward requests to your moodle app on the other machine.  Otherwise this is probably not possible. Explaining reverse proxying is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: @O.Jones I've tried adding a redirect on Server A, so every time www.website.com/learn is accessed it gets 301 redirected to Server B, but the problem then comes in that Server B has no SSL and if I set server B up to have the same DNS as server A things get weird and I just get a "server unavailable" screen. - I will give reverse proxy a shot later today